# Find a string in mongodb with a regex expression and using a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Trying to use mongodb .find with node and I can't figure out how to replace the regex expression with a variable.

So the user is doing a search for text in a blogpost. I'm then using that text to query mongo for any posts that have that text in the title. So if they were searching for posts with a 'Dragon' in them I'm trying to recreate the below using the input, and need it to be not be case sensative.

```
BlogPost.find({ title:/Dragon/},
```

````
app.post('/', async(reg, res) => {
    const searchTerm = `/${reg.body.search}/i`;
    console.log(searchTerm);
    const blogposts = await BlogPost.find({ title: searchTerm });

    res.render('index', { blogposts });
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for anyone who comes across this in the future. By creating an new instance of RegExp with the variable passed to it. The ‘i’ being to make it case-insensitive.

```
app.post('/', async(reg, res) => {
  const searchTerm = reg.body.search;
  const blogposts = await BlogPost.find({ title: new RegExp(searchTerm, 'i') });
  res.render('index', { blogposts });
});
```